# Meaning of gosh all, git-up in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, lyrics

In the song *Jeepers creepers* by Louis Armstrong, there is a line that goes like this:

> Oh, gosh all, git up, how'd they get so lit up?

It refers to the eyes of a person. My question is: what does "gosh all, git up" mean in this sentence? I think *gosh all* is a simple exclamation. The Merriam-Webster dictionary defines git-up as

> drive, energy, aggressiveness.

This makes no sense to me.

Comment: //Oh gosh, all git  up//. To be git up=to be dressed up, to be dressed in fancy clothes. BUT, it can also mean, and I think it means here: to be excited.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the interpretation of song lyrics (which in this case are bordering on [scat singing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing) anyway).

Comment: I honestly had no idea it was scat singing; Jeepers creepers turned out to be a known version of Jesus Christ, so I assumed this has a meaning as well.

Comment: "Jeepers creepers" is not a version of Jesus Christ-- it is a minced oath, or substitution for the name. In this day and age when the f-bomb is dropped so casually in everyday conversation it might be difficult to understand that at one time in history it was a blasphemy to use "Gods name in vain". However, no one hearing it (either then or now) would think it had anything to do with Jesus. It is the same as "Golly", or "Gee", or "Gosh". That being said, the expression "git up" is probably eye-dialect for _get up_. The defintion in MW is likely referring to a shortened form of "git up and go".

Comment: The main purpose of _git up_ seems to be to set up the rhyme with _lit up_, no more. Your eyes (peepers) are bright and starry.